# Why yeoman backbone app doesn't run in "dev" mode?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, yeoman

I've just generated some backbone app using Yeoman and backbone-generator.

```
yo backbone --template-framework=handlebars
```

And made testView with some test template.
After grunt build , if I launch app from dist directory, it works flawlessly.
But when trying to see my app in "dev" mode using grunt serve it gives me error:

```
"GET http://localhost:9000/scripts/templates.js 404 (Not Found)"
```

Should it be so? If not, what is the possible problem I should look for?
ATM google guided me only to similar issues.
Running build every time is very time consuming.

**UPDATE:**

Grunt serve gives error:

```
Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp" file (ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty...
```

Comment: What I've noticed is, that if I edit some template, grunt serve will refresh my browser tab and app works! But then if I edit some JS code, without touching templates, browser tab will refresh and give the same old error, until I don't edit templates once more.

Comment: Are you running `grunt build` and then attempting to use 'dev' mode, or is 'dev' mode just not working while running from `dist/` does?

Comment: "'dev' mode just not working while running from dist/ does"!

Comment: which is your node version?